# how to predict how many years stay in college?

Tags: regression, classification, predictive-models, modeling, survival

I have a data set to predict how long in years does a student stay in college.
The dependent has value like 0.5, 1, 1.5.etc,. I used classification methods like SVM, decision tree but the accuracy is like 30%, which is so low. I tried to round up 0.5 to decrease the levels but still got low accuracy.

So I doubt if it is a classification.

The frequency of number of years is like this

```
   0.5    1  1.5    2 2.25  2.5    3  3.5    4 4.25  4.5    5 5.25  5.5 
   758  223  357  118    2  182  120  840  287    1  576  158    1  261
```

[image]

I also tried linear regression and svm. RMSE is like 1.4 which translate to 1.4 years? I am not sure if the accuracy here is very bad or bad?

And also, I tried Cox PH regression, the question is that some students graduated before say 4 years and I do not know what is the right censoring time here.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a problem of the estimator/classifier you're using. It just seems that you need more predictor variables and maybe more observations.

Comment: Also there seems to be something weird going on with your data. More than half your observations stay only 0.5 a year? 3080 leave after a year, but only 2340 leave (presumably graduate) after 4? Given that, it's not surprising that accuracy is like 30%.

Comment: @YannisVassiliadis I just updated the frequency table. yes, there are lots of 1st year dropout or transfer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use linear regression, at least to start, and examining the assumptions using the usual graphical methods.

I don't think you have censoring, unless I have misunderstood. Do you have people who are *still* in college when you collect data? Then they would be censored because you would not know how long they will stay.

To evaluate the model, I'd look at actual values vs. predicted values. See how big the differences are. But, if your results are poor, it may just be that your variables don't do a good job of predicting years in college.